# How do StackExchange sites associate user accounts and OpenID logins?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, openid, user-accounts, openid-provider, account-management

I love StackExhchange / StackOverflow's approach to integrating OpenID.

As I understand it, the process goes something like this:

- If a user signs up with an OpenID provider (i.e. Google), StackOverflow (or similar site) creates an account for the user and associates the OpenID with that account.
- An existing user can associate multiple OpenID accounts with his/her StackExchange account.

I would love to emulate this behavior because I haven't seen it nearly as user-friendly on other sites.

I know StackExchange is built on ASP.NET MVC, but am not sure whether it uses the standard ASP.NET credentialing model and then adds the OpenID provider in a separate DB table or what.

So, my questions are:

- How does StackExchange create these accounts? Do they Create a user in the standard ASP.NET MVC provider and then associate the ID, or is there a separate process?
- how does StackExchange allow additional OpenID provider accounts to be associated with an existing account?

Thanks in advance for any help you can give!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The StackExchange [sites use](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/openid-one-year-later/) the [DotNetOpenAuth](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/) library (previously known as DotNetOpenId library).

You basically need a `User` table and a `User_OpenID` table with a one-to-many relationship. [Scot Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheWeeklySourceCode25OpenIDEdition.aspx) has a good basic article or try a [more in depth overview](http://www.plaxo.com/api/openid_recipe)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for; wasn't sure if there was more to it than that or not. Perfect -- thanks for the quick help!