# How to centralize logins OpenID in django?

Tags: python, database, django, openid, django-sites

I have split my Django application into two sites with different databases. I use **OpenID** (`python_openid-2.2.5`) for authetication/registration but users of ***site A*** are different from ***site B***. 

How can I do to centralize logins between apps running on different databases? 

And I want a database only for OpenID. I have seen this [article by Joseph Smarr at Plaxo](http://www.netvivs.com/openid-recipe/) and this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4395190/how-do-stackexchange-sites-associate-user-accounts-and-openid-logins) but i don't know if this is the same with python.

How can I accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**django-cas - CAS (Central Authentication Service)**](https://bitbucket.org/cpcc/django-cas/overview) this is what i use for a centralized auth system